# How to generate multiple high charts in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am able to generate one chart. But here there one situation where I need to generate multiple(one or more) charts. Please help me to it with ng-repeat.

JSON data for multiple charts

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "seriesData": [
      {
        "name": "Times",
        "data": [
          [
            1505347200000,
            20
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Prices",
        "data": [
          [
            1505347200000,
            80
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Cleaner",
        "data": [
          [
            1505347200000,
            40
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Other",
        "data": [
          [
            1505347200000,
            40
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "seriesData": [
      {
        "name": "Donut",
        "data": [
          [
            1505347200000,
            20
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Ice Cream",
        "data": [
          [
            1505347200000,
            20
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Tea",
        "data": [
          [
            1505347200000,
            40
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Coffee",
        "data": [
          [
            1505347200000,
            20
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Find the code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TXJE6/273/

Comment: just repeat the directive

Comment: @Sajeetharan tried repeating the ng option for the chart but it is not working

Comment: you need to repeat the directive itself

Comment: use it like this `<hc-chart ng-repeat="item in [1,2]" options="surveyResultChoice" class="chart" >Placeholder for generic chart</hc-chart>`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka how to seriesData here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `ng-repeat` on series only, because other chart metadata doesn't change:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataOfSeries">
  <hc-chart options="surveyResultChoice" 
            data="data" 
            class="chart" >Placeholder for generic chart</hc-chart>
</div>
```

And your directive will look like:

```
app.directive('hcChart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="chart"></div>',
        scope: {
            chartOptions: '=',
            series: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {

            scope.chartOptions.series = scope.series;

         Highcharts.chart(element[0], scope.chartOptions);
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[Fixed demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4ta4g64/)</kbd>

---

As I side note I would create chart inside directive and only would pass series from controller